# Set Spring profile in Tomcat web app with no web.xml file

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jax-rs, spring-profiles

I have a webapp that is a RestEASY JAX-RS application and that uses the latest servlet specifications, such as Java EE annotations so that I don't need to create a `web.xml` file.

The webapp is bundled as `foobar.war` and dumped into the `webapps` directory in Tomcat. In fact the same `foobar.war` is deployed twice in the same Tomcat instance, once as `foobar.war` and the other as `foobar#demo.war` (which maps it to `foobar/demo` as you know).

I configure each mounted webapp by placing `conf/Catalina/localhost/foobar.xml` and `conf/Catalina/localhost/foobar#demo.xml` files, that look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Environment name="foo" type="java.lang.String" value="bar"/>
</Context>
```

In my JAX-RS application I pull in the value of `foo` from JNDI using `java:comp/env/foo`.

So now I added a Java-based Spring configuration named FooBarConfiguration. I load it in my JAX-RS application using `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(FooBarConfiguration.class)`. That all works fine.

So now I've added two profiles to `FooBarConfiguration`, one named `foo` and one named `bar`. But now... how do I tell the webapp which Spring profile to use? (Remember that I have no `web.xml` file.) Obviously I have to set `spring.profiles.active` somewhere. But where?

Because the documentation spoke of "environment" and "JNDI", I crossed my fingers and added an environment variable to `conf/Catalina/localhost/foobar.xml`:

```
  <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" type="java.lang.String" value="foo"/>
```

No luck.

I can't set a system property, because that will apply to *all* the webapps, and the idea here is that each `foobar.war` instance (`foobar.war` and `foobar#demo.war`) could each have a different profile specified.

I suppose I could manually pull it out of the Tomcat environment myself, using `java:comp/env/spring.profiles.active`, but then where do I set the value? (I thought maybe `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` would have a constructor where I could set the profile, or at least have a profile setting, but that also seems to be missing.)

(Plus if I'm manually pulling out the setting from JNDI and setting it myself, I might as well switch to the more lightweight Guice and manually load the modules I want. I'm only using the humongous, clunky Spring because it promised to allow easy selection of profiles.)

How can I indicate, external to my WAR file, on a per-webapp basis, which Spring profile I'm using?

Answer (score 2):

You can set active profiles in many ways. Since you were searching for it via `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` constructor, the one  described [here in spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-enable) might suit you.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("development");
ctx.refresh();
```

Comment: what you describe is a valid workaround, but the link you gave clued me in to the real solution: use a `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext`, which will pick up the profile automatically using JNDI, as I was wanting. Thanks for the response which pointed me the way to the solution, which I've given as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` instead of `StandardServletEnvironment`.

The trick is to get Spring to use a `StandardServletEnvironment`, which looks in several places including JNDI `java:comp/env/...` for `spring.profiles.active`. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-property-source-abstraction .

My problem is that `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` uses a `StandardEnvironment`, which only looks in a few places for the profile designation. Switching to a `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` made Spring use a `StandardServletEnvironment`:

```
final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext =
    new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
webContext.register(FooBarConfiguration.class);
webContext.refresh();
```

Now my webapp environment configuration in `conf/Catalina/localhost/foobar.xml` works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Environment name="spring.profiles.active" type="java.lang.String" value="foo"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work if the var name is set to `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`? does Spring not see environment vars defined in Context XML?